# Cohomology of pushforward of coherent sheaf and connected components

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a proper morphism, $\mathscr F$ a coherent sheaf on $X$.

If we know something about the connected components of fibers of $f$ can that give us a useful upper bound for $i$ such $H^i(Y, f_*\mathscr F)$ is not zero?

For example coverings of $\mathbb{P}^1$ by itself can give $H^1$ to the trivial line bundle.

Comment: I think this is unlikely. Zariski's main theorem implies that $f$ factors as a composition of a morphism whose fibres are connected with a finite morphism. So if such an upper bound existed, it could be extended to any morphism (since finite morphism have no non trivial relative cohomology).